# Can spark write shuffle data to hdfs?

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, bigdata

I am joining a small table to a huge table in Spark using SparkSQL.
I am having the problem that my local disks are being filled by the shuffle writes about halfway through the join.

Is there a Spark setting that I can use to spill shuffle data not to local disk but to our hdfs storage (large Isilon cluster)?

Is there some other way to make a join where the output is larger than my combined local disk storage?

I have made sure that both input tables are partitioned and that the output table is partitioned.

I do not care about performance of the query, I just want it to finish without crashing.

### Details

I am running Spark 1.5.1. I am also open to attempting using hive, but my experience tells me that this crashes even faster.

For more details on my cluster you can also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370134/how-to-increase-hive-concurrent-mappers-to-more-than-4).

Comment: I find odd that you are having this kind of problem... you are partitioning your RDDs by key right? if this is the case you should not be having much shuffling during the join

Comment: Yes, due to this problem I ended up aggressively partitioning both tables. Perhaps the problem is due to the nodes having comparable disk (500 GB) and RAM (256 GB). Somehow Spark might use a specific fraction of memory for local disk space.

Comment: I think the purpose of shuffle is to move data the executor need to the node where the executor is on, so why you store it on distributive storage hdfs? It contradicts the purpose of shuffle

Comment: @calvin, because the shuffle data exceeded by far the amount of local disk space. And shuffle does two things: 1) move data to the right machine, 2) serve as a temporary storage while computation continues.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, this is a **local** dir, where HDFS is a shared file-system.

You can decrease the shuffle data by tuning the way Spark does the data partition (which depends on your input and treatment).

Comment: I ended up solving the issue by using an nfs share for the local dir.Otherwise I would run out of disk space on my large multi terabyte joins.

Comment: Damn! you should not use NFS for this purpose (this is very slow) rather decrease shuffle data quantity by tuning partition.

Comment: We have low latency 40 GB/s NFS (per node) so it is not too bad. Unfortunately I tried all sorts of partitioning, but spark kept insisting to write everything to localdir instead streaming the data through.

Comment: ho nice, what NFS do you have? You can accept my answer then post another question about how to decrease shuffle

Comment: We are using Isilon nodes from Dell EMC. They provide redundancy, high availability, snapshots, etc. with support for ftp, smb, nfs, and hdfs protocols. It is pretty neat, if pretty expensive.

Comment: This can not always be done.  If you need to shuffle 1PB of data, and have only 0.5PB of RAM to store it in, you need to spill 0.5PB.  With perfect partitioning and 1000 executors each on one node, you'll still need to spill 500GB per node.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can storage your results in hdfs,but can't put the data computing to hdfs. Because the computation must  occur on memory or on disk.

Comment: So this means that the maximum "join" that I can do is disk size * number of disks ? Or I guess it just means that I will have to do the data just a little bit at a time.

Comment: As shuffle occurs during the computation process,hdfs can only storage data and can't be used to computate.

Comment: "Because the computation must occur on memory or on disk" note -> hdfs is also "on disk"

Answer (score 0):

If your local disk is not enough, find a free volume and  set the `'spark.local.dir'`, which is expected to be closer for better performance.

Comment: Yes, I attempted that but it does not work for a shared drive as the different nodes would overwrite each others data. I will try again with a separate folder for each node.